# Set thumbnail/small image/base image from .csv import in Magento

Tags: php, magento, csv

I'm working on a Magento website, and some products' images are uploaded but not set to any fields (base image/small image/thumbnail):

[image: image fields]

There is over 800 products with this problem so I can't do this by hand. I tried importing a CSV with a Dataflow Profile, but even if there's no error, it still stays the same, my CSV looks like this:

```
sku;store;websites;status;visibility;image;small_image;thumbnail
100018930;admin;base,kitchen;1;1;/images/100018930.jpg;/images/100018930.jpg;/images/100018930.jpg
....
```

Maybe the issue is that the image is already uploaded?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks.

PS: Magento's version of this website is 1.5.0.1...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by using MAGMI (http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) an alternative to the default Magento CSV Importer, really fast (it took around 1 hour for 800 products with Magento, and 2min30s with Magmi).